# how to dry up exception handling in twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

So I have an app which solely rely on twitter, and the twitter gem. As people know it requires a lot of exception handling to make it solid.

I'm trying to write exception handling, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the best way. For instance you have the:

```
Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests
```

which you receive if the user has hit the maximum request limit (which resets every 15 min or so). However in that case I'd have to add this exception handling to every single call I make to the API, or is there a better way to handle all these exceptions?

For instance can I call it on Twitter, instead of things like twitter.search, twitter.follow?

My question is essentially, with all the exception handling required when writing an app that relies solely on an API what's the best way to go about doing things?